# Is double "pure stalemate" reachable in a normal game?

Tags: puzzles, stalemate

Define "pure stalemate" as a position where the player is not in check, and has no legal moves, even without considering whether a move would place them in check. (So every piece is blocked by pieces of the same colour).

Define "double pure stalemate" as a position where regardless of which player's move it is, that player would be in pure stalemate.

**Question:** Is it possible to reach double pure stalemate in a normal game of chess? (And if so, prove it...)

I can construct a position of single pure stalemate, which I think is probably reachable, although possibly not. (It's not obviously *not* achievable).

However, mirroring that position does not quite work as it requires 4 pawn captures to achieve and there are only 3 pieces missing from the opposing side.

Comment: Believe it or not, this question has already been asked and solved here: Is it possible to have a double self-smothered stalemate?

Note: I prefer the term “smothered” because “pure” has another technical meaning for problem mates and stalemates.

Comment: Amazing, yes, thank you.